# 2D numpy array does not give an error when indexing with strings containing digits

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

When I create a one dimensional array in numpy and use a string (containing digits) to index it, I get an error as expected:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(15)
>>> a['10']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: field named 10 not found.
```

However, when I create a two dimensional array and use two strings for indexing, it gives no error and returns the element as if the strings are converted to integers first

```
>>> b = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> b[1, 2]
7
>>> b['1', '2']
7
```

What's going on? Why don't I get an error in the two dimensional case?

Comment: This is kind of cool ... I'd never seen this anywhere ...  Interestingly enough, `np.empty((3,5))[1,'2']` works, but `np.empty((3,5))[1]['2']` doesn't.  Consistent with the behavior you report above.

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer* -- this answer is bound to be incomplete

I think what you're seeing is a consequence of [fancy sequence indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer).  Since strings are actually sequences, you're getting the values of the string one character at a time and converting them to "`intp`" objects (which presumably just uses python's `int` function)-- which is then giving you your array index.

This also explains the 1D case:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        print idx

a = Foo()
a[12]
a[12,12]
```

Note that in the second case a `tuple` is passed whereas in the first case an integer is passed.

---

The piece of this that I still don't understand is demonstrated by this test:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(156).reshape(13,12)
print a[12,3] == a['12',3]   #True -- I would have thought False for this one...
print a['12',3] == a[('1','2'),3]  #False -- I would have guessed True for this..
assert( a[tuple('12'),3] == a[(1,2),3] )  #This passes, as expected
```

Feel free to try to explain this one to me in comments. :)  The discrepancy might be that numpy deliberately leaves strings alone when converting to a sequence of `intp` objects in order to more smoothly handle record arrays...

Comment: I had arrived at the same conclusion, but I still don't know why the 1-tuple case don't work : for example `b['1']` and `b[('1')]` raise an error whereas `b[('1',)]` and `b[1]` give the right result.

Comment: I had thought that it had something to do with the fact that the value passed in the 2-d case is a `tuple`. But I think one would have to dig into the source to fully understand why. Possibly once `numpy` receives a tuple, it then happily tries to convert what's in the tuple to an integer or an array, but it won't do that for arbitrary strings. (I don't think it does it one character at a time, though -- for example, if you pass `'12'` in a tuple to a 5x5 array, `numpy` complains about an out-of-range index.)

Comment: @georgesl -- The 1-tuple case is easily explained (Numpy checks whether it gets a tuple and unpacks each element in the tuple separately).  But there are still inconsistencies here.  `arange(42)[list('12')]` still fails :-/.  As I said, It's definitely an incomplete answer.

Comment: @georgesl part of the reason for this is that `('1')` is not a tuple, the tuple operator (if that is the right word) is the comma, not the brackets.

Comment: Hmmm, the `arange(42)[['1', '2']]` case is fun. I expect its because it sees '1' is iterable, so it is handled like `arr[[[1], [2]]]`, which is a special case because probably because a single list (and not a tuple).

Comment: @seberg -- that isn't completely consistent with `arange(100).reshape(100,1)[list('12'),0]` though.  There pretty much has to be some special case string handling with works differently if `__getitem__` sees a tuple or a different datatype as far as I can see.  The big question is "**why??** (and my money is on record array compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, note that the first case (a single string), is probably to do with support for recarrays, which use strings as field names.

Please do *not* rely on the second case. Numpy is extremely free about indexing with non-arrays, since if it is a non-array (and not a slice and not None), it will simply try to convert it into an integer array, which is well defined for these strings. However this is *not* by design, its because too much software relies on this behaviour (at least partially) to actually change it, and quite honestly, while this make somewhat make sense for floats which are forgotten to be cast, it really doesn't for strings.

---

Some more details for @mgilson. considering that all of this is off label usage, it really cooks down to implementation details. For example a single string is currently special cased for recarrays even if its not a recarray, but a tuple of strings is only special cased for recarrays.

Now a list of strings, is somewhat special cased, since they are not tuples, but act like one *most* of the time. This may be a small bug... Because it finds a sequence inside of it, it triggers fancy indexing, but "forgets" to convert it to an array. Though I would generally use tuples to denote multiple axes.